# MS Project can't set assignment.Cost (illegal argument)

Tags: exception, task, ms-project

I'm writing an Add-In to export the tasks of MS Project to JSON. Also I want to import them.
Now I got the problem to set the assignment.Cost value. For some reason there comes an Illegal Argument Exception. Do not pay attention to the naming, such as 'asd'. It's just for testing. ;-) It would be great if you can show me, what I'm doing wrong.

```
if (!task.Kosten.Equals("0"))
                {
                    project.Resources.Add("asd");
                    foreach (Resource resource in project.Resources)
                    {
                        if (resource.Name.Equals("asd"))
                        {
                            Double.TryParse(task.Kosten, out Double kosten);
                            newTask.Assignments.Add(newTask.ID, resource.ID);
                            foreach (Assignment assignment in newTask.Assignments)
                            {
                                if (assignment.ResourceName.Equals("asd"))
                                {
                                    //This is the line which throws an Exception.
                                    assignment.Cost = kosten;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Assignment Cost field is calculated. This is also true for the Resource Cost field; only the Task Cost field is an entry type.

[Microsoft reference page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cost-fields-c9ddf12c-8396-49e4-8edd-07aebd862f10)

Comment: Thank you alot! Sometimes you don't see the obvious things. :-D